# How to configure Postfix with new gmail authentication?

Tags: email, postfix, email-server, gmail

Gmail past month has disabled the classic authentication method called "non secure access". Before basically it was enough to configure SMTP `smtp.gmail.com` and access credential in `main.cf`. Now how could I configure postifix to use gmail as relay?

Comment: The people that downwoted could explain what is the problem with the question?

Comment: Your question shows zero research effort. Also, the same question has been asked and answered multiple times here since Google activated this behavior.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider I have searched here and I haven't found any similar question, If I have missed it rather than downvoting it was enough to comment and provide a link  In addition if a question is duplicated the correct procedure is to mark it to close as duplicate referencing the analogous question rather than downvoting without even provide an explaination.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow the instructions in the URL in the error message returned when you try and sign into the Gmail SMTP server and create a App Specific password.

https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833?hl=en

EDIT: The SMTP server will be responding with an error similar to:

```
535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at
535 5.7.8 https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials g5-20020a50d5c5000000b004356c0d7436sm11008465edj.42 - gsmtp
```

Comment: I haven't such instruction link you talk about, just a message that repots the authorization has been refused. Could you add it?

Comment: Trust me, in the logs somewhere will be a the response from the SMTP server when it fails to authenticate with your normal password. But anyway, the answer is a App Specific Password.

Comment: It's not lack of trust I have checked and there isn't such link

Comment: Do you have **2-Step Verification** turned on on your Google Account? The Google support doc linked by hardillb says "App Passwords can only be used with accounts that have 2-Step Verification turned on." If you don't have that, perhaps the error message is different with no link.